# A superuser/administrator that can read/write everyones calendar in Exchange Server 2013

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2013

I know one way is to use a script and user `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` against every user

But is there any other way to create an administrator user that can read/write everyone's calendar and not other folders like mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The add-mailboxfolderpermission is the only way to limit the access to the calendar folder. Anything else would be the entire mailbox.

My preferred method, if possible, is to use a group. The group has to be mail enabled. Then you can just set the permission once and add/remove user accounts as required. The script required is a single line - nothing complicated.